# Google Protocol Buffers as a 3D Graphics game format

Tags: 3d, protocol-buffers

I am looking for a convenient client side only format for persisting 3d scene data
Would Google protocol buffers serve as good format for persisting and loading complete scene data for a scene exported from say 3d s max or blender?
I mean the mesh, animation and scene data would be stored in the protobuf format client side and loaded from a game (there is no client server interaction as of now...but might be in future versions...so I assume protobufs would always provide that flexibility)?

Comment: Protobuf is a general-purpose format, so my default answer here would be "sure", but to answer whether it can be done *conveniently* one would need to know quite a bit about the particulars of what makes up a "scene". It certainly has the key primitives etc, support for sub-objects, lists, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a valid solution and I thought about trying this out myself. Google uses the protocol buffers for their internal data processing because they are able to store the data in a very compact way (unlike e.g. XML) while also allowing extensibility of the data structures (new fields can be added to a structure and the old code can still read it).

I'd say giving it a try would definitely not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. An optimized binary format will still take less memory and need less time for loading. ProtoBuf is good when you don't want to make a custom file format, and need it to be extensible.

Comment: While it is true that you can probably squeeze a few extra bytes out by doing it all manually, protobuf is still very efficient - both in terms of bandwidth and processing costs.

Comment: ProtoBuf clearly is a good candidate for the prototype. When it comes to optimizing performance at your app, you can then still replace the file format.
Traditionally, file formats for Game levels for example have been highly specialized and optimized. They at least used to contain precomputed indexes and even precomputed ambient lighting. And I guess they've tried to squeeze every bit of the file format, to minimize loading time...
But for starting, ProtoBuf seems very convenient and well-capable.